# (Online) Dictionary for German legal terms

Tags: legal-terms, germany, legal-research, research, database

Where can I find a search engine or (online) dictionary which returns the definition and usage of a given term?

Example:

```
Search: [Fachkunde ]

Returns
 
Type            Source                      Link
definition      1. SprengV Abschnitt VII    https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/sprengv_1/
definition      WaffG §22                   https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/waffg_2002/__22.html
usage           ASiG §7                     https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/asig/__7.html
usage           BGB §123                    http://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/bgb/__123.html
usage           BGB §345                    http://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/bgb/__345.html
```

Comment: Have you tried Google scholar?

Comment: @ohwilleke Google scholar can search in books but it did not help in this case.

Answer (score 1):

If a classic "offline" dictionary would benefit you, the publisher C.H. Beck has a couple, for instance [this one by Linhart](https://www.beck-shop.de/linhart-woerterbuch-recht/product/14257963).